# Pymongo Connection with MongoDB atlas - Error 111 Connection refused

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, ssh, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I'm setting up a cron job, where it fetches some data from MongoDB atlas in Python3 through Pymongo in Cpanel. I always get a Error 111 Connnection refused.

I using python3.6 and pymongo-3.9.0, Cloud MongoDB-4.0.2

I have tried via SSHtunnel forwarder, but not sure how to give host_ip_addres, where MongoDB is in cluster

```
class DbConnection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connectionServer = "mongodb+srv://"
        self.userName = "name"
        self.userPass = "pass"
        self.connectionCluster = "@temp-cluster0-lt2rb.mongodb.net"
        self.connectionDb = "developmentDB"

    def db_connect(self):
        ''' This function is used to connect to remote db with authentication
            Return type --> returns the url string of the db
            parameters--> self
            '''
        try:
            connectionUrl = self.connectionServer + self.userName + ":" + self.userPass + self.connectionCluster + "/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
            print(connectionUrl)
            myClient = pymongo.MongoClient(connectionUrl, port=12312)
            db = myClient.test
            print(myClient.test)
```

I'm expecting it to connect to the MongoDB cluster DB and read/Write the documents through it.

Comment: I would not recommend **mixing** the use of a connection URI and other settings like `port` in the `MongoClient` options. If you want to construct a URI, I would suggest including the `port` details **within** the URI itself. i.e `mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>`. Note also that despite this being regularly included on atlas connection strings **NO Database** i.e `/test` should be included in the connection URI **at ALL**. This is in fact interpreted by the driver as the **authentication database**, and in in fact **incorrect** for Atlas connections.

Comment: The correct authorization namespace for Atlas ( and really for ALL MongoDB deployments when done correctly ) is `admin`. This is the **default** when no other authentication database is provided. Also the `retryWrites` etc are also really optional and probably should **not** be included ( IMHO ) until you actually understand what they are doing. So really not a *beginners* option, to be fair.

Comment: @NeilLunn URI with port is not possible. Always get an error like **pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: mongodb+srv:// URIs must not include a port number** Thanks for your suggestio

Comment: Ah! I was not paying attention **mongodb+srv** connections **SHOULD NOT CONTAIN PORTS  - PERIOD**. That's your problem. The whole point of the `mongodb+srv` is that to **DO NOT** include that additional information since it's all contained in the DNS lookup result. Ports etc are **ONLY** to be used with `mongodb://` connection strings.

Comment: @NeilLunn  Thanks, but resulted in a new error like **pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: temp-cluster0-lt2rb.mongodb.net:38012: [Errno 11001]**  getaddrinfo failed

Comment: Sounds more generally like the machine you are attempting connection from has connectivity issues in either it's own firewall settings or that indeed you have not white-listed the IP of that machine with your Atlas install ( please don't allow connections from everywhere to your Atlas cluster ). In fact that last one is the most common cause of that error as many people miss that you ***need*** to add the allowed IP addresses, and probably only checked the "my current ip address" option when initially testing

Comment: @NeilLunn, Thanks I almost tried most things. I allowed all the IP(0.0.0.0) to MongoDB atlas and even added domain ip as well. Moreover, I trying to connect from the cpanel python, but the cpanel SSL certificate was expired. Thinking will it be a problem. Even trying to change ports, SSHtunnelforwarding but No luck. It works completely fine in my pc but in the cloud hosting when establishing connection, fails with different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

*So the comments for the question solved the issue, so i'll just put this here for any future reference*

The error can be resulted for must people because of a miss-configuration when moving from a self hosted MongoDB to a Remoted host service (Like MongoDB Atlas)

So, the `+srv` is [DNS Seed List Connection Format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#dns-seed-list-connection-format).

When switching from port based connection to DNS seed based connection, we should remove any **port** configuration from our connection string, i.e:

```
class DbConnection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connectionServer = "mongodb+srv://"
        self.userName = "name"
        self.userPass = "pass"
        self.connectionCluster = "@temp-cluster0-lt2rb.mongodb.net"
        self.connectionDb = "developmentDB"

    def db_connect(self):
        ''' This function is used to connect to remote db with authentication
            Return type --> returns the url string of the db
            parameters--> self
            '''
        try:
            connectionUrl = self.connectionServer + self.userName + ":" + self.userPass + self.connectionCluster + "/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
            print(connectionUrl)
            // myClient = pymongo.MongoClient(connectionUrl, port=12312)
            // We remove the PORT 
            myClient = pymongo.MongoClient(connectionUrl)
            db = myClient.test
            print(myClient.test)
```